# Scala, Casbah: MongoCollection.insert compilation errors

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, casbah

I am trying to write function that writes data to MongoDB using Casbah toolkit:

```
  import com.mongodb.casbah.WriteConcern
      import ...

  def saveRecord(rec: MongoDBObject) {
    mongoColl.insert(rec)
  }
```

I get the following errors:

```
1) No implicit view available from Object => com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBObject.   

2) not enough arguments for method insert: (implicit dbObjView: Object => com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBObject, implicit concern: com.mongodb.WriteConcern, implicit encoder: com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.DBEncoder)com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.WriteResult. Unspecified value parameter dbObjView.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure without full imports, but try to change `MongoDBObject` to `com.mongodb.DBObject` or add `import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._`

Comment: Thanks, this one works. But for some reason `import com.mongodb.casbah._` does not. Why?

Comment: `import com.mongodb.casbah._` imports package, but `import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._` imports object `Imports` which contains all implicits and type aliases for casbah.

Comment: Does it mean that package import does not import object definitions?

Comment: It allows you to use objects and classes without package prefix, but it's not recursive, so you need to directly import object `Import` if you want to use it's content.